# how to make sure the proxy works or not in macOS iterm

Tags: curl, http

Now I am set the proxy in `.zshrc` like this:

```
alias proxy='export all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890'
```

and check using the `env` command in terminal, shows the proxy env value like this:

```
all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890
```

but when I using this command to fetch some data in iTerm, shows error like this:

```
➜  ~ curl https://google.com
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to google.com:443
```

when I am using google chrome browser to access the same url, it works fine. I did not know where is going wrong. how to check the proxy works? when I using this command to check the 7890 port, shows output like this:

```
➜  ~ lsof -i:7890
COMMAND     PID           USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google      680 xiaoqiangjiang   23u  IPv4 0x46cd4f2ea35741d7      0t0  TCP localhost:53183->localhost:7890 (ESTABLISHED)
Google      680 xiaoqiangjiang   25u  IPv4 0x46cd4f2ea3463747      0t0  TCP localhost:64063->localhost:7890 (ESTABLISHED)
Google      680 xiaoqiangjiang   26u  IPv4 0x46cd4f2ea346cc67      0t0  TCP localhost:64087->localhost:7890 (ESTABLISHED)
Google      680 xiaoqiangjiang   27u  IPv4 0x46cd4f2ea347b747      0t0  TCP localhost:64114->localhost:7890 (ESTABLISHED)
Google      680 xiaoqiangjiang   28u  IPv4 0x46cd4f2ea3516cb7      0t0  TCP localhost:64209->localhost:7890 (ESTABLISHED)
```

why the curl command in iTerm did not work? I tried this command，it worked：

```
➜  react-admin git:(umi) curl -x socks5://127.0.0.1:7890 https://baidu.com
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>bfe/1.0.8.18</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And I check the ISP IP： `113.97.201.136`,it is the proxy server ip. this is the verbose log:

```
➜  Downloads curl -x socks5://127.0.0.1:7890 https://google.com -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:7890...
* SOCKS5 connect to IPv4 8.7.198.46:443 (locally resolved)
* SOCKS5 request granted.
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 7890 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to google.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to google.com:443
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I answer here and not in comment, but I don't have reputation high enough to comment (joined today).
But I don't get what you're doing.
You're defining an alias, so when you type `proxy` you're making that export so letting curl use it... but you didn't say if be fore the actual curl command you typed proxy. Beside this, wouldn't it be better to write this into your `~/.curlrc`:

```
 proxy = "socks5://127.0.0.1:7890"
```

or if you really want to use alias in your `~/.zshrc`?

```
alias curl="curl -x socks5://127.0.0.1:7890"
```

I suppose in your own solution the you're missing quotes:

```
all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890
```

should be

```
 all_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:7890"
```

thus

```
alias proxy = 'export all_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:7890"'
```

---

This should be a comment I cannot post because of low repu yet --> the `curl -x socks5://` command works because you're telling curl to use a proxy: it's the same with the alias I told you to put into `~/.zshrc`.